# access a third party library method

Tags: ruby

I am using a 3rd party open source library.

In the library, there is one file (**Aaa-Bbb/Ccc.rb**)'s code looks like this:

```
module Aaa
  module Bbb
    module Ccc
      def get_data
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my Ruby project, I need to call the `get_data` method from above module. So I tried this:

```
require 'Aaa-Bbb/Ccc'
module MyMod
  def my_func
     # Error: undefined method 'get_data' for MyMod:Module (NoMethodError)
     data = get_data
  end
end
```

When I run above code, I get error:

```
undefined method 'get_data' for MyMod:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Why? How to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you have a problem in the line `module Aaa module Bbb`, what does the actual line look like?

Comment: It is exactly the same line except names.

Comment: OK looks like it's 3 level of nesting, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include` the required module in your own module:

```
require 'Aaa-Bbb/Ccc'

module MyMod
  # Including the required module to make all its methods available here.
  include Aaa::Bbb::Ccc

  def my_func
     data = get_data
  end
end
```

Comment: And I still need `require 'Aaa-Bbb/Ccc'` on the top?

Comment: @Leem.fin yes, you require the file, and include the module.

Comment: Hmm...I still get the same error, here is the third party library: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb   I need to call `get_preferences(name)`

Comment: Did you use the updated include line? It's using `Aaa::Bbb::Ccc`

Answer (score 0):

`require` will process the given file in the current instance of the interpreter, but has no effect on your current namespace. You use `include` to import methods from another namespace into your current namespace; note that `include` does not read in or have anything else to do with files.

So, if you start with

```
require 'Aaa-Bbb/Ccc'

module MyMod
    def self.my_func; data = get_data; end
end
```

(Note that I've added a `self.` in front of the function name because I assume from the nature of your example that you're not trying to use objects here.)

After processing the `require` method, the interpreter has processed the equivalent of

```
module Aaa; module Bbb; module Ccc
    def self.get_data; ...; end
end; end; end

module MyMod
    def self.my_func; data = get_data; end
end
```

This has defined two methods whose fully qualified names are `Aaa::Bbb::Ccc::get_data` and `MyMod::my_func`. When `my_func` is executed it will search first for a `get_data` method in module `MyMod`, but there isn't one. So it will then search the top level object (module) for a `get_data` method and, not finding it there, fail with your `NoMethodError` exception.

There are two ways you can go look in other modules not directly above yours for the method. First, you can simply call it directly with the fully qualified name:

```
data = ::Aaa::Bbb::Ccc::get_data
```

Second, you can use `include` to bring all of the methods from another module into your own module's namespace:

```
include ::Aaa::Bbb::Ccc
data = get_data
```

You'll note that I use an initial `::` in the examples above to force the search for `Aaa` to start at the top-level object/module. This isn't necessary in this simple example, but it's generally good practice when you're dealing with deeply nested modules because if you were in a nesting such as

```
module Xxx; module Aaa; module MyMod
    def self.my_func; ...; end
end; end; end
```

Using just `Aaa` instead of `::Aaa` would find the enclosing `::Xxx::Aaa` module instead of the top-level `::Aaa` module.

Note also that it can be convenient, when doing deep nesting, to define modules using

```
module Aaa::Bbb::Ccc; module Ddd
    def self.f; ...; end
end; end
```

to save on the nesting and the use of `module`/`end`, but you do need to make sure in cases such as the above that modules `Aaa` and `Aaa::Bbb` have already been defined in previous code that's been loaded.